# Grouping ands and ors in a PHP if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

This is probably a simple answer, but I was curious if you have php code like say this:

```
if($_SESSION['id'] == '000001' || $_SESSION['id'] == '000002') {
```

Could those values be grouped somehow? My thoughts would be something like:

```
if($_SESSION['id'] == ('000001' || '000002')) {
```

Not a huge deal, just wondering if it is possible. If not, it seems like it should be.

Comment: Prolly worth having the values in an array and iterating over it, doing the check for each value in the array. Might be inefficient though.

Comment: While your attempt at grouping may look intuitive, PHP (like most other languages) does work in that way. The inner expression `('000001' || '000002')` would first be evaluated to `true` because one or more of the values is not false (both, in this case). Then the main expression becomes `if ($_SESSION['id'] == true)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is kind of possible using `in_array()`:

```
if (in_array($_SESSION['id'], array("000001", "000002")))
```

or alternatively using `switch`:

```
switch ($_SESSION["id"])
 {
   case "000001":
   case "000002":
    // do something
   break;

   default:
   break;
 }
```